# Angular form required/pattern validation is not working

Tags: angular, validation, angular-validation

I have a simple form which contains one textbox. I added required and pattern validation on this textbox. It's added red borer on the textbox when textbox is empty or not matching pattern but not displaying error message.

I have created a sample example also. Please find it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2osndq)

Can you please help here?

Comment: You need at add the mat-error component yourself and display it if that control has an error

Answer (score 0):

is for example:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="messageForm.get('message').hasError('required')">
              Contact full name is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
```

Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Can you please update https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2osndq so that it will help me.